# function inside function with same name in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I pass function to a function with same function name and handler name, which one will get precedence ? and how to access each of those two inside function in case in need to do recursion as well as refer to the passed function. See below code.

```
var f1,f2;

(function f(f){
    return typeof f(f2); /*please check below comments for output of this line*/
  })(function(f1){ return 1; });

/* this will call the passed function,why not recursion will not happen here? */
```

Answer (score 3):

The function parameter gets precedence over the function's own name.  If you shadow or overwrite a variable, you can't access it (unless it's a shadowed global).

Solution is to use different names.

Answer (score 0):

The recursion doesn't happen simply because the argument of the function get precendence than the function itself. here is an example that shows it:

```
(function f (f) {
   return f.name;
}) (function funcName () { }); // this will return funcName
```

if we change the name of the argument to f1, f will become the reference of the function itself

```
(function f (f1) {
   return f.name;
}) (function funcName () { }); // this will return f
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use jquery. So I want to ask where do you have declared your functions? inside

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
        function f(){
            return 'this is local function inside anonymous function, so it's invisible for recursion in aside of current document ready'
        }
    });
//or here? 
    function f(){
    return        'this function is a window object property, and must be visible for recursion';
    }    
    </script>
```